# vb6 winsock control RemoteHostIP truncates the last digit from IP address

Tags: vb6, tcp, network-programming, sockets, winsock

Hi i am writing a socket client/server application in VB6.
i have the following code

```
Private Sub sockMain_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
    If sockMain.State <> sckClosed Then
        sockMain.Close
    End If
    sockMain.Accept requestID    
    Debug.Print "Accepted connection from: " & sockMain.RemoteHostIP & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

its printing the IP but the last digit is missing example, if my connection is from "192.168.1.123" then it shows "192.168.1.12" only

Comment: If socket connection is established are you sure the connection is established from 192.168.1.123. Did you check what IP is shown as the remote IP in tcpview software.

Comment: If the IP shows 192.168.1.123 then i dont there is any problem with the socket APIs. The problem will be with the way you are printing the IP.

Comment: I am able see the active connection and able to transfer data, and in the debug mode if i check the connection state, the socket is in Connected state only. there is no issue with the connection. but the control RemoteHostIP is always shows the IP by truncating the last digit, is i connect client from local i am getting 127.0.0. instead of 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the exact same code and it works on my machine.  I tried using telnet from the same machine, and also from a laptop and the correct IP address was printed in both cases.

I have to agree with ckv and say that its the way you are printing `RemoteHostIP`.

Comment: If you used exact same code you must have used same function to print the IP also right? So you mean with same code as Dharma has mentioned above you are getting correct IP.

Comment: Hi CKV and quamrana, still i am not getting why in my system the last digit is missing. even if i set a watch for the socket object and checked during debug, still shows the RemoteHostIP by truncating the last character.

Comment: @Dharma: OK, that's bad.  Can you try a minimal version of the program on some different hardware/OS?

Comment: Except vb6 winsock control, other programming languages line VC++, C# and VB.Net i am able to get the RemoteIP address complete.

Comment: @Dharma: So what hardware/OS *are* you using to get the symptoms you describe in your question?

Comment: Pentium(R)D CPU 2.8 GHz/Windows XP sp2

Comment: @Dharma: Any chance of trying it on Vista or Windows 7?  btw My machine is Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Currently i am tied with other schedules..i will check this later,may be this week end.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in KB957924 Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update ([link](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7030)) in both v1 and May 2009 v2.   This is why some people can duplicate it and some can't.  It also is limited to the second and subsequent usage of the control.

It is discussed [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1546795&page=1).

As a really ugly workaround you can call `recvfrom` in the `wsock32.dll` lib with the `sockMain.SocketHandle`, a small buffer and the `MSG_PEEK` parameter (`&H2`) to retrieve the socket address directly.  This must be done before calling `sockMain.GetData()`.  Then you have to parse out the IP address yourself.  I can post code that does this for the specific case I'm using (UDP) if requested.

I'm not sure it will work in your case since it looks like you're using TCP and Accept.